# PostgreSQL percentile_cont and aggregations

Tags: postgresql, aggregate

I have to compute three 99th%ile with postgresql function percentile_cont.
two of them are related to single column, the third one is about the difference of the two previous columns, BUT I have to compute the last one after an inner join, and it is not clear to me how to do.

```
SELECT
    TableA1.a,
    TableA1.b99,
    TableA2.b99,
    **percentile_cont(0.99) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY (TableA1.b - TableA2.b))::bigint**
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            a,
            percentile_cont(0.99) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY (b))::bigint as b99
        FROM TableA 
        GROUP BY
            a
    ) TableA1
INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            a,
            percentile_cont(0.99) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY (b))::bigint as b99
        FROM TableA
        GROUP BY
            a
    ) TableA2
ON
    TableA1.a = TableA2.a
```

The fourth field selected (percentile_cont(0.99) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY (TableA1.b - TableA2.b))::bigint) is impossible because the field b from the two subqueries has been already aggregated.

Any suggestion on how to rebuild the query?

Thank you in advance,
Lorenzo

Comment: Just to be more clear, my problem is exactly the "TableA1.b - TableA2.b" percentile computation, that I should compute after the Join but I cannot since fields 'b' are no longer available.